# How to update UserID with leaderboard using Firebase Real time database,

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Transaction to save leader board score with Unity3D and RealTime database.
My ultimate goal is to:

1. Find if  `UserID` already exists in database leaderboard
   .
2. If `UserID` exists than check if the NEW score (From Game) is HIGHER
       than the OLD score (From DataBase), if so delete OLD score and place the NEW score.
3. If `UserID` DO NOT exists, just add the NEW score if it is HIGHER
       than the lowest score of the whole database list. *Pretty much what it does now from the code example below.*

One way i thought of is to Sort the list by `score`, than i can pass the whole list one by one and find the userID position and score, afterwards somehow delete the found userID and place the new score..

I tried to sort it, but nothing seems to make sorting work here.

No doubt, This is a tricky one.

Code:

```
TransactionResult AddScoreTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
    List<object> leaders = mutableData.Value as List<object>;

    if (leaders == null) {
        leaders = new List<object>();
    } else if (mutableData.ChildrenCount >= MaxScores) {
        // If the current list of scores is greater or equal to our maximum allowed number,
        // we see if the new score should be added and remove the lowest existing score.
        long minScore = long.MaxValue;
        object minVal = null;
        foreach (var child in leaders) {
            if (!(child is Dictionary<string, object>))
                continue;
            long childScore = (long)((Dictionary<string, object>)child)["score"];
            if (childScore < minScore) {
                minScore = childScore;
                minVal = child;
            }
        }
        // If the new score is lower than the current minimum, we abort.
        if (minScore > score) {
            return TransactionResult.Abort();
        }
        // Otherwise, we remove the current lowest to be replaced with the new score.
        leaders.Remove(minVal);
    }

    // Now we add the new score as a new entry that contains the email address and score.
    Dictionary<string, object> newScoreMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    newScoreMap["score"] = score;
    newScoreMap["email"] = email;
    newScoreMap["userId"] = userId;
    leaders.Add(newScoreMap);

    // You must set the Value to indicate data at that location has changed.
    mutableData.Value = leaders;
    return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
}

public void AddScore() {
    if (score == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) {
        DebugLog("invalid score or email.");
        return;
    }
    DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to add score {0} {1}", email, score.ToString()));

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Leaders").Child("ClassA");

    DebugLog("Running Transaction...");
    // Use a transaction to ensure that we do not encounter issues with
    // simultaneous updates that otherwise might create more than MaxScores top scores.
    reference.RunTransaction(AddScoreTransaction)
        .ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.Exception != null) {
            DebugLog(task.Exception.ToString());
        } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            DebugLog("Transaction complete.");
        }
    });
}
```